# Two ways to find ID in Capybara - why does one fail and the other doesn't?

Tags: cucumber, capybara

I want to simply "click" on a link using Capybara and Cucumber. I have an element that looks like this:

```
<a class="to-right" id="create-account-link" href="https://somewebsite.com/">Create account</a>      //url is different when I test it
```

I tried the following two methods in my step definition:

```
page.find('[@id=create-account-link]').click       //works

AND

page.find('#create-account-link').click            //doesn't work
```

I would like to find out why the latter doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: Which driver do you use?

Comment: What you experience is too strange. Please provide a simple reproduction case including test code, JS, CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by putting

```
Capybara.default_wait_time = 5
```

in my hooks.rb file. It usually waits for two seconds, and apparently the xpath reference is quicker than the other one.

Comment: Now it is Capybara.default_max_wait_time = 5